# Finish .click() execution so next function can run on page which click function will browse to

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, jquery-deferred, deferred

I have a setinterval function that finds link tags and clicks on each link. I want to call another function(SecondFunction) after .click() function has been completed(Which means it is on new page by clicking on `<a>` tag).

But debugger goes into SecondFunction before going to new page. I want 2nd function to be called after a link has been clicked so  second function is called on that next clicked page.

Can it be done using callback or defer object, If yes then how?

```
setInterval(function(){
            $Findinks= Get all links

            $Findinks.each(function(index, value){       
               1. Click on each link which should take it to new page;    
               2. SecondFunction() // This function should be called on new page 
which we will get by step 1
},1500)

 function SecondFunction(){
setInterval(function(){
},1000)
}
```

Comment: Once you navigate to a new page any JavaScript that was in the old page is gone and can not execute. You can use AJAX to get new content which your JavaScript can use to replace what is displayed in the current page, but it is not a new page.

Comment: It remains on the same page but show something different so it does not reload the page and JavaScript is still there. @Makyen

Comment: Psuedo-code isn't much use here. You need to show the actual code. All the interesting stuff is in "click on each link which should take it to new page".